# If div have Height apply css to DIV - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is possibile to make this?

If DIV inside page is > 600 px apply background color: red to #TWO

In JQuery

I create this but don't work correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.extend($.expr[':'], {  
    over100pixels: function(a) {  
        return $(a).height() > 600;  
    }  
}); 

$('div:over600pixels')
    $("#TWO").css("background-color", "red");
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if ($("#yourDiv").height() > 600)
    $("#TWO").css("background-color", "red");
```